# How do I send random messages?

Tags: discord, discord.js

*(Now... yes, I know that the title might be nonsense.)*

**So let's say I have 6 embeds. You know, like... a game die.**
**I want to send one of these embeds once I run the command `$roll`.**
***Here's how I coded it:***

```
message.reply(`${ one || two || three || four || five || six }`);
```

However, every time I run the command, it only says *One*... [Here's an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDMAj.png)

Help me with this, please.

Comment: Please do some research before asking. Just searching "how to send a random message in discord.js" will give you 10+ answers, and you can easily find *many* more by digging a bit deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `one || two || three || four || five || six` this, It is always one because one is always true.
So if you wanna send a random value, try this code

```js
const choices = [one, two, three, four, five, six]
message.reply(choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function randomnumb() {
    var rand = [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three",
      "four",
      "five",
      "six"
    ];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];
  }
  
  message.channel.send(randomnumb());
```

Comment: Provide an explanation to your solution, not just the code

Comment: Thanks, but I alredy fixed the issue thanks to @kiki7000 .